# Draw multiple circle on a map, Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, leaflet

I am working on a project related to maps. I use leaflet in Angular.

Here, I want to draw circles in the map according to the coordinates given in the api. But I don't know where and how to use loop

I tried putting it in layers but it gives me an error. Below I tried to put a loop directly in the constructor, but I don't know how to addTo() or call back. please help me

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Circle, circle, icon, latLng, Layer, Map, marker, polygon, tileLayer } from 'leaflet';
import { ServicesService } from '../service/services.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

  list: any
  
  constructor(private service: ServicesService) {
    this.service.getList().subscribe((response: any) =>{
      this.list = response
      this.list.forEach((i: any) => {
        circle([i.location.lng, i.location.lat], {
              color: 'red',
              fillColor: '#f03',
              fillOpacity: 0.5,
              radius: 5000
        })
      })
    })
  }

  options = {
    layers: [
      tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        attribution: '&copy; OpenStreetMap contributors'
      }),
      circle([28.0339, 1.6596], {
        color: 'red',
        fillColor: '#f03',
        fillOpacity: 0.5,
        radius: 5000
      }),
      circle([ 46.95, -122 ], { radius: 5000 }),
    ], 
    zoom: 10,
    center: latLng([ 28.0339, 1.6596 ]),
  };
  

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

Comment: What does your template look like? Do you use ngx-leaflet wrapper or just Leaflet?

Comment: whats the error message?

Comment: not error message here, i just want to know how can i use loop or something here to be able to make multiple circles

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.